# In PostgreSQL, today centered data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `Foo` with unique field `date`.

Is it possible to write query, that fetches `date == today` centered `Foo`s?

For example I have 100 `Foo`s. And I want only 5 of them. But I only want, something like: `[<before-40days>, <before-30days>, <today>, <after-100days>, <after-101days>]`.

What I currently do is:

`a = SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY ASC;`

`b = SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY DESC;`

and then in my application `result = a + b`.

Is it possible get today centered `Foo`s with one query?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text.) And perhaps I'll understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION to combine both queries: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-union.html

```
(SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY DESC)
ORDER BY ...;
```

Its very simple, but the network-overhead will be reduced.